# error installing libtorrent with boost

Tags: boost, libtorrent

on Lubuntu 14.04 64 bit, I am getting this configure error when I try to install de libtorrent library:

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.35... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking for exit in -l/usr/local/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/... no
checking for exit in -lboost_system-/usr/local/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/... no
configure: error: Could not link against boost_system-/usr/local/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/ !
```

I executed this:

```
alberto@alberto-virtual-machine:~/trabajo/libtorrent-rasterbar-0.14.7$ ./configure --with-boost-system=/usr/local/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi
```

there are this files on the directory:

```
alberto@alberto-virtual-machine:~/trabajo/libtorrent-rasterbar-0.14.7$ ls /usr/local/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/
error_code.o  libboost_system.so.1.57.0
```

I haven't much idea about static libraries, could someone help me please? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The argument --with-boost-system takes either:

1. A library name suffix (like mt, which some distros use)
2. A full path including the library name

You did not pass in a full path with the library name, so the configure script interprets it as (1) and it fails to link against that library. Instead, try:

```
./configure --with-boost-system=/usr/local/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/libboost_system.so
```

Comment: I have tried and the result is exactly the same, thank you anyway.

Comment: you still get this output in the error? "boost_system-/usr/local/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/"

Comment: yes, this is the output: checking for exit in -lboost_system-/usr/local/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/libboost_system.so.1.57.0... no
configure: error: Could not link against boost_system-/usr/local/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/libboost_system.so.1.57.0 !